# Julia: Atom, Plots.jl, and plotlyjs() - window scaling issue

Tags: julia, plotly, autoscaling, plots.jl

I am using Plots.jl with plotlyjs(). Whenever I use it within atom, the plot does not scale to the window (see picture). Is that a known issue or is there a fix for it?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: try resizing the plot pane after the first plot, then plot to it again. Sometimes there's some startup trouble with the sizing. After doing that, could you open an issue on Plots.jl and report?

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) Manually resizing leads to the correct sizing temporaneously. After plotting it again the problem persists. I'll go ahead and open an issue on plot.jl

Comment: cf https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1074